# Solr Search with subtraction on 2 field

Tags: solr, field, subtraction

I want to search in solr with the subtraction on 2 indexed field greater than a specific number.

For example, suppose I have an indexed table with field `(int) start` and field `(int) end`, I want solr to find all the entries with `end-start > 100`.

How to construct such a query with solr?

Something like this: `?q=sub(end,start):[* TO *]` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you just add another field subtraction at index time, with the value of `end-start` and then use `subtraction:[100 TO *]`